# Выровнять высоту кнопок в колонках на Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap

Использую Bootstrap 4.
Есть несколько (для примера пусть будет 2) колонок кнопок, количество кнопок в колонках разное, может меняться.
Как можно выровнять высоты кнопок так, чтобы колонки были одинаковой высоты?

```
<div className="btn-group-vertical mt-4 mb-4" role="column">
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-secondary bg-dark">1</button>
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-secondary bg-dark">2</button>
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-secondary bg-dark">3</button>
</div>
<div className="btn-group-vertical mt-4 mb-4" role="column">
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-secondary bg-dark">1</button>
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-secondary bg-dark">2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял Вашу задачу относительно одинаковой высоты колонок, то просто добавьте `btn-group-container` класс `d-flex`:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn-group-container d-flex">
  <div class="btn-group-vertical my-4" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group-vertical my-4" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ой, точно. Не заметил, что надо растянуть

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, ну и раз уж используется бутстрап, то писать свой css практически нет необходимости - почти всё есть в классах

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn-group-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn-group-container">
  <div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">3</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Салам...подскажи какой шрифт используется ?

Comment: @MaximLensky `system-ui, -apple-system, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", "Liberation Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji"` вот такое. Какой именно не знаю. Шрифты тут заданы CSS переменной. Я посмотрел это в Firefox, во вкладке вычислено. Или Computed вкладка в chrome, но в хроме не так удобно

Comment: получается берётся из системы ?

Comment: @MaximLensky не могу быть в этом уверенным, надо к пустой странице подсоединить этот bootstrap CSS и посмотреть на вкладу Network, куда идут запросы, возможно, где-то могут подключить шрифты, но это не точно